# MYSQL retrieve row in one table where it occurs the most in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm tying to write a script that will detect any duplicate guests in my database so they can be merged.

I'm try to select the guest id where they have the highest count of bookings in my bookings table as that is the guest i want to merge into. So if there are any duplicates it will return one row and the id will be of the guest with the most bookings.

Not sure how I can do this?

```
select 
    count(*) as duplicates,
    guests.id as id,
    guest_name(null, null, guests.id) as guest_name
from
    guests
        left join
    bookings_guests_link
        left join
    bookings ON bookings.id = bookings_guests_link.booking_id ON guests.id = bookings_guests_link.guest_id
        and bookings_guests_link.primary_client = 1
group by title , firstname , lastname , street , city , postcode , state_id
having duplicates > 1
order by count(bookings.id) desc , duplicates desc
```

Any help appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you each guest and the number of bookings.

You could create a temp table with this

```
SELECT g.id, g.firstname, g.lastname, street, city, postcode, state_id,
       COUNT(b.id) AS NoOfBookings
FROM guests g
LEFT JOIN bookings_guests_link bgl
  ON g.id = bgl.guest_id
LEFT JOIN bookings b
  ON b.id = bgl.booking_id
GROUP BY g.id, g.firstname, g.lastname
```

This will give you a list of duplicate guests

```
SELECT title, firstname, lastname, street, city, postcode, state_id
FROM guests
GROUP BY title, firstname, lastname, street, city, postcode, state_id
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

So you just need to find the matches between the two and decide how you actually want to merge the records.